# json parsing using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

My data is like this:

```
   {
       "region":  
             ["{'price':'119','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'4.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996'}",   
              "{'price':'112','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'9.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996'}",   
              "{'price':'118','volume':'20000','pe':'0','eps':'1.22','week53low':'92','week53high':'134.4','daylow':'117.2','dayhigh':'119.2','movingav50day':'115','marketcap':'0','time':'2015-11-25 05:13:34.996'}"  
              ]  
    }
```

I am doing like below;

```
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray regionArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("region");
```

How do I get each price..

```
for (int i = 0; i < regionArray.length(); i++) {

             JSONObject item = regionArray.getJSONObject(i); 
             System.out.println(item.getString("price"));
        }  

Caused by: com.gemstone.org.json.JSONException: JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
```

Comment: Each item in the json array is a string, why are you trying to parse it as JSON?

Comment: I want to access the each element of the array..is it not possible

Comment: It's possible, but since it is a string you should use `String item = regionArray.getString(i)`. If you need to get the price you'll need to parse the string, as it's not JSON.

Comment: lets say I have an embeded ,then how do i find it..

Comment: What is an _embeded_?

Comment: Now i have changed form '(' to '{'

Comment: `JSONObject item = new JSONObject(regionArray.getString(i))`. But really, you should use a json object instead of a string. Don't over-complicate your code.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array of Strings, not of JSON objects, so you can't do JSON object methods on it.

In order for your code to work, your JSON would have to look like this:

```
{
  "region": [
    {
      "price": "119",
      "volume": "20000",
      "pe": "0",
      "eps": "4.22",
      "week53low": "92",
      "week53high": "134.4",
      "daylow": "117.2",
      "dayhigh": "119.2",
      "movingav50day": "115",
      "marketcap": "0",
      "time": "2015-11-25 05:13:34.996"
    },
    {
      "price": "112",
      "volume": "20000",
      "pe": "0",
      "eps": "9.22",
      "week53low": "92",
      "week53high": "134.4",
      "daylow": "117.2",
      "dayhigh": "119.2",
      "movingav50day": "115",
      "marketcap": "0",
      "time": "2015-11-25 05:13:34.996"
    },
    {
      "price": "118",
      "volume": "20000",
      "pe": "0",
      "eps": "1.22",
      "week53low": "92",
      "week53high": "134.4",
      "daylow": "117.2",
      "dayhigh": "119.2",
      "movingav50day": "115",
      "marketcap": "0",
      "time": "2015-11-25 05:13:34.996"
    }
  ]
}
```

I just replaced that automatically in a text editor. You can actually let the numbers out of their "" enclosure if you want.

Have a look at it here: http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

And here's some info on Json: http://www.json.org/

Comment: Lets say I have to { instead of (.Then How do I find price

Comment: @Aman With the JSON I entered here, you can find the price without changing your code. Your code, as you put it in your question, should work just fine.